# Expressing the domain of a list variable

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

In the context of describing a simulation model, I need to express the domain of a list variable. Verbally, I would say something like:

> A sequence, indexed from 0 to *t* - 1, where each item is a real number between 0 and 16 (inclusively).

What I have so far is:

$\left(a_0,\ldots,a_{t-1}\right), a \in [0:16]$

Does that make sense? Is there a better way to say this?

Comment: You could write $a_0,...,a_{t-1}\in\{0,...,16\}$. The notion $[0:16]$ is not very common in mathematics. Also there is no $a$ but only $a$'s with subscripts. So you can not refer to $a$. Of course, you could say that $a$ is the name of the whole sequence, but then $a\in\Bbb R^t$ or $a\in\Bbb R^{\{0,...,t-1\}}$, which looks unreasonably complicated.

Comment: It is commong two write multiple elements before $\in$ like in $a,b,c\in X$ to indicate that all of them belong to the set $X$. The curly braces $\{$ and $\}$ around $0,...,16$ are important, because they indicate that this collection of numbers from $0$ to $16$ is a set. This then amplifies the interpretation that all of the $a_0,..,a_{t-1}$ are individual elements from this set, i.e. each one is a number between $0$ and $16$. The notation $[0:16]$ might not be bad, but just unusual. It look more like computer code to me (MATLAB maybe?).

Comment: However, here is another way: $(a_0,...,a_{t-1})$ is a sequence with $a_i\in\{0,...,16\}$ or $0\leq a_i \leq 16$ as long as it is clear that the $a_i$ are natural numbers, otherwise you should state $a_i\in \Bbb N$ additionally.

Comment: I got the interval notation from there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Notations_for_intervals. In my case, $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{N}$. But thanks for the help! If you're willing to turn your comments into an answer, I'm willing to accept it.

Comment: Correct; an interval on the real line is denoted with $[a,b]$; thus $[0,16]$ is fine.

Comment: Yes, writing $[0:16]$ instead of $[0,16]$ is totally a programmer's mistake. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for seeing through it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some misinterpretation (in the comments below your question), here the hopefully helpful answer:

Intervals are usually written with commas like $[0,16]$ instead of $[0:16]$. The last one was known to me from some programming languages as the definition of a range of integers, so I assumed it to be from $\Bbb N$. I am sorry about this. Then of course the way to go would be something like this:
$$a_i\in[0,16],\quad i=0,...,t-1$$
or
$$a_i\in[0,16],\quad i\in\{0,...,t-1\}.$$

Comment: Would something like this make sense as well? $(a_i)_{i=0}^{t-1},\quad a_i \in [0,16]$

Comment: Yes, also possible and actually very common to denote sequences.